# VB script in excel works on 32 bit os but not 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook. the following piece of code works on 32 bit windows but not on 64 bit windows.

```
Private Function wwGetMD5HashPart(ByRef rngData As Range, ByRef lcellCounter As Long, ByRef hhash As Long) As Long
    Dim ocell As Range
    Dim vValue As Variant
    Dim lresult As Long

    On Error GoTo E1
    'Fill it with the contents of the range
    For Each ocell In rngData.Cells
        lcellCounter = lcellCounter + 1
        If Not IsEmpty(ocell.Value) Then
            vValue = CStr(ocell.Value)                                     'rasey o40611
        Else
            '         must use a value for the empty cell not at all likely to be used be accident.
            vValue = "^ " & CStr(lcellCounter)   'rasey 040611
        End If                                                             'rasey 040611
        lresult = CryptHashData(hhash, StrPtr(vValue), LenB(vValue), 0&)   'rasey 040611
    Next
    wwGetMD5HashPart = lresult

     Exit Function

E1: If gbDebug Then
        MsgBox "Error in wwGetMD5HashPart"
        Stop
    End If


End Function
```

I get a compile error: type mismatch

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: Off subject, the default argument passing method is `ByRef` so you do not need to write it.

Comment: Are you running 64-bit Office?  The typical advice for maintaining compatibility is to use the 32-bit version, even on a 64-bit OS, unless you're really sure you want the 64-bit version.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-office-HA010369476.aspx

Comment: @Taosique it errors on `Private Function wwGetMD5HashPart(ByRef rngData As Range, ByRef lcellCounter As Long, ByRef hhash As Long) As Long`. @simpLEMAn i am not sure what you mean. @TimWilliams it is 32 bit office and I have PTrSafe declared where required.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264421%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Use the **LongPtr** data type for **Long** when running 64bit. It decides if its 32 or 64 bit, and whether to use Long or LongLong.

**Note:** this will will break if running on VB6. As it does not contain the LongPtr data type. In order to run on both you will have to use a compile time if.

```
#If Vba7 Then 
'Decalre PtrSafe Sub
'Change all Longs to LongPtr
#Else 
'Keep as is
#EndIf
```

**Side Note:** If running on both watch out for the following

```
psudo:
int x = long b 'Works on VB6
```

For VB7 have to change it to:

```
int x = Cint(long b)
```